# How to add data to a nested list in Isar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-isar

I have a class that has `String` and `List` variables. While the application is running, I need to add values ​​for each model separately to this nested `List`. This is something like a TODO list, where there are categories of cases, and each category has its own tasks. Tell me, how can I implement adding tasks to Isar?

This is my model:

```dart
@collection
class Training {
  Training(this.title, this.weekDay, this.exercises);

  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;

  String title;

  String weekDay;

  List<Exercise> exercises = [];
}

@embedded
class Exercise {
  Exercise({
    this.title,
    this.sets,
    this.reps,
    this.weight,
    this.time,
    this.description
  });

  String? title;
  int? sets;
  int? reps;
  int? weight;
  String? time;
  String? description;
}
```

Maybe should make separate collections and link them by reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your `traning` class instance first:

```
final training = Training("My workout", 'Monday', []);
```

Fill with data

```
training.exercises.add(exercise);
training.exercises.addAll(exerciseList);
```

And write to the database

```
await isar.writeTxn(() {
  await isar.trainings.put(training); 
});
```

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if I answered on your question